# How to accept google consent cookies when im web scrapping with Jsoup

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup

I want to scrape data using the Jsoup library from the premier league table page on google but cant get to that web page with out accepting the google consent cookies and I cant find anywhere online that shows how I would go about doing this. I'm guessing I will need to submit the form and then store the cookies in a variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ScoreTrackerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScoreTrackerApplication.class, args);

        final String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=premier+league+fixtures&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIE874IE874&oq=premier+league+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i131i433i512l3j0i433i512j0i131i433i512l5.8107j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sie=lg;/g/11pz7zbpnb;2;/m/02_tc;st;fp;1;;;";

        try {
            final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            //Testing purposes only
            System.out.println(document.body());


        }catch (Exception ex){

        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
<h1 class="I90TVb" id="S3BnEe">Before you continue to Google</h1>
        <div class="AG96lb">
         <div class="eLZYyf">
          We use <a class="F4a1l" href="https://policies.google.com/technologies/cookies?utm_source=ucbs&amp;hl=en-IE" target="_blank">cookies</a> and data to
          <ul class="dbXO9">
           <li class="gowsYd ibCF0c">Deliver and maintain Google services</li>
           <li class="gowsYd GwwhGf">Track outages and protect against spam, fraud and abuse</li>
           <li class="gowsYd v8Bpfb">Measure audience engagement and site statistics to understand how our services are used and enhance the quality of those services</li>
          </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="eLZYyf">
          If you choose to 'Accept all', we will also use cookies and data to
          <ul class="dbXO9">
           <li class="gowsYd M6j9qf">Develop and improve new services</li>
           <li class="gowsYd v8Bpfb">Deliver and measure the effectiveness of ads</li>
           <li class="gowsYd e21Mac">Show personalised content, depending on your settings</li>
           <li class="gowsYd ohEWPc">Show personalised ads, depending on your settings</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="jLhwdc">
           If you choose to 'Reject all', we will not use cookies for these additional purposes.
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="yS1nld">
          Non-personalised content is influenced by things like the content that you’re currently viewing, activity in your active Search session, and your location. Non-personalised ads are influenced by the content that you’re currently viewing and your general location. Personalised content and ads can also include more relevant results, recommendations and tailored ads based on past activity from this browser, like previous Google searches. We also use cookies and data to tailor the experience to be age-appropriate, if relevant.
         </div>
         <div class="yS1nld">
          Select 'More options' to see additional information, including details about managing your privacy settings. You can also visit <span>g.co/privacytools</span> at any time.
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="spoKVd">
        <div class="GzLjMd">
         <button id="W0wltc" class="tHlp8d" data-ved="0ahUKEwjVkZLx_939AhWObsAKHcCBBz4Q4cIICF8">
          <div class="QS5gu sy4vM" role="none">
           Reject all
          </div></button><button id="L2AGLb" class="tHlp8d" data-ved="0ahUKEwjVkZLx_939AhWObsAKHcCBBz4QiZAHCGA">
          <div class="QS5gu sy4vM" role="none">
           Accept all
          </div></button>
```